# Define a Stub for a method with ref parameters, where ref value is not modified

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am working with an interface that I cannot change (for legacy reasons). The interface has methods on it that take `ref` parameters.

In my unit tests I wish to stub out one of those methods on that interface. Crucially I want to change one of the ref parameters, but leave the other unchanged.

I am able to change the parameter that I want to change, but I don't know how to tell Rhino Mocks to leave the other one untouched.

Here is a failing test that highlights the problem (Note that in reality I don't have access to `poco` before I define the stub, as this is instantiated in an external module):

```cs
using Rhino.Mocks;
using Rhino.Mocks.Constraints;
using NUnit.Framework;

[Test]
public void Main()
{
    var serviceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();

    serviceMock.Stub(x => x.DoSomething(
            ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Anything(), null).Dummy, // I don't want to specify null here
            ref Arg<int>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(1), 2).Dummy));

    Poco poco = new Poco{Data = "One"};
    int returnValue = 1;
    serviceMock.DoSomething(ref poco, ref returnValue);

    Assert.AreEqual(2, returnValue); // passes
    Assert.AreEqual("One", poco.Data); // fails
}

public class Poco
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public interface IService
{
    void DoSomething(ref Poco poco, ref int returnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
serviceMock.Stub(x => x.DoSomething(
        ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Anything(), null).Dummy,
        ref Arg<int>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(1), 2).Dummy));
```

With:

```
serviceMock.Stub(x => x.DoSomething(
                 ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Anything(), poco).Dummy,
                 ref Arg<int>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(1), 2).Dummy));
```

The change will replace the calling parameter with `poco`. Then your test will pass.

**Edit:**

To achive the behavior you are looking for you have to implement a custom `AbstractConstraint`. This object will record the incoming value, then you need to specify an `interceptor`(`WhenCalled` method in `RhinoMocks`):

```
class PassValue : AbstractConstraint
{

    public Poco Obj { get; private set; }

    public override bool Eval(object obj)
    {
        Obj = (Poco)obj;

        return true;
    }

    public override string Message
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

The use it in the stub declaration:

```
var p = new PassValue();

serviceMock.Stub(x => x.DoSomething(
            ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(p, p.Obj).Dummy, 
            ref Arg<int>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(1), 2).Dummy))
            .WhenCalled(invocation =>
            {
                invocation.Arguments[0] = p.Obj;
            });
```

Comment: although the test will pass, the parameter is still changed -- in your example, it is changed for exactly the same instance, but in reality I don't have access to the same instance to do this replacement. I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: that's great, thanks! One small point, I don't think you need to reference p.Obj twice, i.e. `ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(p, p.Obj).Dummy,` could be `ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(p, null).Dummy,`

Comment: @ChrisPriest you are right about the null in this example, however in my real code `PassValue` is `PassValue<T>` and `Arg<Poco>.Ref(p, p.Obj)` wrapped in a helper method....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var serviceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IService>();

 var poco = new Poco { Data = "One" };

 serviceMock.Stub(x => x.DoSomething(
                ref Arg<Poco>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Anything(), new Poco { Data = "One" }).Dummy, // I don't want to specify null here
                ref Arg<int>.Ref(Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is.Equal(1), 2).Dummy));

 int returnValue = 1;
 serviceMock.DoSomething(ref poco, ref returnValue);

 Assert.AreEqual(2, returnValue); // pass
 Assert.AreEqual("One", poco.Data); // pass
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as per @old-fox, the test will pass but the parameter is still changed -- in your example, it is changed for another instance that happens to have the same properties. In reality I don't have access to poco to know what properties the replacement should have. I've updated the question to reflect this